# How to change background color for media view in WordPress core?

Tags: wordpress, media

I'm trying to change the background color for the direct media view in WordPress. This is for when a media file is accessed directly from the wp-content/uploads/ directory.

The current HTML output is as follows:

`<body style="margin: 0px; background: #0e0e0e; height: 100%"><img style="display: block;-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;cursor: zoom-in;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);transition: background-color 300ms;" src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/MyImage.png" width="572" height="810"></body>`

I want to change the background color in the body style from #0e0e0e to another color. I understand that this might require changing the WordPress core, and I'm aware of the risks associated with that.

Could anyone point me to the specific core file that generates this output, or suggest an alternative solution?